# I can't install any extension on vscode on Mac

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I got the error message while installing **flutter** and **dart** extension for the first time on vscode. Please help me to find the solution.

"Error while installing 'Flutter' extension. Please check the log for more details."

````
[2022-09-30 16:40:57.149] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:40:58.492] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:40:58.493] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:40:58.494] [renderer3] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 16:41:54.391] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:41:54.395] [renderer3] [error] Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 16:41:54.397] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:41:54.411] [renderer3] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 16:46:31.935] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery {"name":"Canceled"}
[2022-09-30 16:46:31.951] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery {"name":"Canceled"}
[2022-09-30 16:48:06.048] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:49:21.493] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 16:49:21.544] [renderer3] [error] Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 16:49:21.547] [renderer3] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 16:59:20.359] [renderer3] [error] Error: File not found
    at g.handleSetInputError (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2727:95841)
    at async g.setInput (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2727:95081)
    at async r.doSetInput (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2725:6429)
    at async r.doOpenEditor (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2725:4791)
    at async r.openEditor (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2725:3783)
    at async vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2932:16794
    at async C.doOpenCodeEditor (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1360:58414)
    at async C.openCodeEditor (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:661:60416)
    at async S.open (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:603:47669)
    at async a.open (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:603:49132)
[2022-09-30 17:23:21.933] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:23:21.935] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:24:37.356] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:24:37.406] [renderer3] [error] Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 17:24:37.425] [renderer3] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)
[2022-09-30 17:24:37.607] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:24:37.619] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/dart-code/flutter/3.48.0/1662044600382/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:24:42.991] [renderer3] [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://dart-code.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Dart-Code/extension/flutter/3.48.0/assetbyname/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code.Manifest {}
[2022-09-30 17:24:42.992] [renderer3] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/doipantsin/Downloads/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:70:8688)```
````